# How to validate forms with dynamic ngMessages

Tags: angularjs

[This plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/y6KkD3cbl3rsv8NZn4c1?p=preview) has a form with a field that only allows to enter `aaa`. Note that the error message is set in the controller, not in the html. When the user clicks on `Submit` they should see the message, but the message is not shown. What's wrong with this code?

HTML

```
<body ng-app="ngMessagesExample" ng-controller="ctl">

  <form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm()">
    <label>
      This field is only valid when 'aaa' is  
      <input type="field1"
             ng-model="data.field1"
             name="field1"
             required />
    </label>
    <div ng-messages="myForm.field1.$error" style="color:red">
        <div ng-message-exp="required">{{errorMsg}}</div>
    </div>

  <br/><br/>
  <button style="float:left" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('ngMessagesExample', ['ngMessages']);

app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    if ($scope.field1 != 'aaa')
        $errorMsg = "This field should be 'aaa'";
    else
        $errorMsg = "";
  };      

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget my previous answer.
Easiest and most robust is actually to make a new directive.

```
var app = angular.module('ngMessagesExample', ['ngMessages']);
app.directive("aaa", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",

        require: "ngModel",

        link: function(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$validators.aaa = function(modelValue) {  
                return modelValue === 'aaa';
            }
        }
    };
});
```

And your controller:

```
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.data = {
    field1: ""
  }
  $scope.submitForm = function(){
     //extra whatever code
  }
});
```

Your HTML should be this:

```
<body ng-app="ngMessagesExample" ng-controller="ctl">
  <form name="myForm" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm(myForm)">
    <label>This field is only valid when 'aaa' is</label>  
    <input type="field1"
         ng-model="data.field1"
         name="field1"
         required aaa/>
    <div ng-messages="myForm.field1.$error" style="color:red">
      <div ng-message="required">FIELD IS REQUIRED!!</div>
      <div ng-message="aaa">FIELD MUST BE 'aaa'</div>
    </div>
    <button style="float:left" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I updated the plunk based on your comments [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/UKTHa2VhjfMLTst3JSdG?p=preview) but it doesn't work, any ideas? thanks